# Calling redirect within static method of other class

Tags: laravel

In my controller, I call an outer static method which checks the user status and it tries to redirect but it fails.

```
public function my_method(){
    SomeOtherClass::redirect_if_not_logged_in();
}
```

And in SomeOtherClass, the is code:

```
static function redirect_if_not_logged_in()
{
    $check_login = Auth::check();

    if($check_login === false){
        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

What am I missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to read the docs and understand how middleware works because it will likely save you from many similar headaches in the future.  For brevity though, you can always refactor the code so the static method always returns something...

```
static public function redirect_if_not_logged_in()
{
    $check_login = Auth::check();

    if ($check_login === false) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then check if the response from that method is not null, and if it isn't return it from your controller.

```
public function my_method()
{
    $results = SomeOtherClass::redirect_if_not_logged_in();

    if (null !== $results) {
        return $results;
    }
    // continue
}
```

Comment: This approach will prevent code execution beyond the authentication check in the controller

Comment: But my_method also returns a view.

Comment: If you return the redirect response from the authentication check the call to a view will never be made. I'm not sure how practical it would be to check the authentication externally. You can call abort as per my answer, admittedly this would only return an error response and not redirect the user to another page.

Comment: Then refactor the code.  The idea is that if you want to redirect, you need to return the redirect.  Have your static method return null if logged in.  Then put a condition on it so that if the static method returns anything not-null, just return it.  Otherwise move on.

Comment: Alternatively I guess some middleware could be applied to the route? This is laravel after all

Comment: That would be by far the best solution since the middleware already exists out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you abort in the static method then you will not have to worry about returning redirect responses. This will allow you to execute code beyond your authentication check in the controller.

```
static function redirect_if_not_logged_in()
{    
    if(!Auth::check()){
        abort(403);
    }
}
```